# I thought that everything in matplotlib is a QWidget. Apparently Figure is not. My interface accepts QWidgets. What to do?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am learning matplotlib with python. the task is to embed a plot in a UI. the plot is to be redrawn upon reception of some event.

The UI application takes a QtDesigner generated class, whic is basically 4000 lines of

```
self.BRIGHTNESS = QtGui.QSlider(ZenMainForm)
self.BRIGHTNESS.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(463, 73, 32, 131))
```

etcetera, generates some other objects and appedns them to the generated class, before it gets drawn.

I have identified this process and been able to add sliders, radio buttons and other standard QWidget-derived objects.

However, now I need to embed the said graphic. There are plenty of **[tutorials](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html)**, but they create a Picture on a Canvas and then add Axes to it. Unfortunately, I do not understand this process, and, above all, do not understand **how can I create a QWidget, containing a mutable plot**. From there on, it is one line to integrate it in the application.

Comment: Note: In matplotlib, all artists (a `Figure` is an artist) are backend-independent.  It's the `Canvas` that's actually drawn on and it's the `Canvas` that's a `QWidget`.

Comment: I don't have any executable code for you, but the basic idea is this:
- create a FigureCanvas which is a QWidget (e.g. `from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg \
import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas`
- this canvas holds your figure, so you should do something like:
`self.fig = Figure(..)
 self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(...)`
- every FigureCanvas usually has a method `update_plot()`, which is called to update the plot. This is where you want to implement your plotting routine. I hope I got it about right and it helps.

Comment: the canvas classes in the tutorial you link to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted everything not relevant from the tutorial. Then I started integrating my code into the tutorial code, until it broke. This highlighted my mistake. Thanks everyone for the invaluable comments!

Below is the modified minimal version of the tutorial. Just use DynamicMplCanvas as an ordinary QWidget.

```
# Copyright (C) 2005 Florent Rougon
#               2006 Darren Dale
#
# This file is an example program for matplotlib. It may be used and
# modified with no restriction; raw copies as well as modified versions
# may be distributed without limitation.

from __future__ import unicode_literals
import sys, os, random
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg, etc.)."""
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        # We want the axes cleared every time plot() is called
        self.axes.hold(False)

        self.compute_initial_figure()
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)


class DynamicMplCanvas(MplCanvas):
    """A canvas that updates itself every second with a new plot."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        MplCanvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(timer,
                               QtCore.SIGNAL("timeout()"),
                               self.update_figure)
        timer.start(1000)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        self.axes.plot([0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 0, 4], 'r')

    def update_figure(self):
        # Build a list of 4 random integers between 0 and 10 (both inclusive)
        l = [ random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(4) ]
        self.axes.plot([0, 1, 2, 3], l, 'r')
        self.draw()
```